# Complicated sorting based on date Yii2

Tags: yii2

I am creating a search in yii2.

```
$q = $_GET['q'];

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => company::find()
        ->where('name like :name', [':name' => "$q%"])
]);
return $this->render('index', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider,]);
```

I also have two date properties (valid payment from and to):

```
from_date and to_date
```

I need to display the result starting with the one who has a valid payment first.

How should the qyery look if I want to display the companies with valid payment first? They should all sort on name ASC..

I have a function to get this value in the model, but not i the query:

```
public function getValidPayment()
{
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    return (($this->from_date <= $today) && ($today <= $this->to_date));
}
```

This is yii2

Thanks!

Edit: Just to clarify what I need:

1. Query companies based on name (name like :name')
2. priority the one that has valid from and to date (from_date and to_date)
3. display the rest that does not have a valid from and to date (both groups in the query should sort on name ASC).

Maybe I should do this in 2 queries, and somehow combine them?

Comment: Where are you implementing this? In `GridView`?

Comment: I am using a dataprovider, but looping trough them in the index view using a for loop. The problem is getting the correct order in the query. This is a large database with one million companies listed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'query' => company::find()
  ->select([
    'valid_payment'=>"(('".$today."'<=to_date) AND (from_date<='".$today."'))",
    name,
    //...some fields you required in your grid
  ])
  ->where('name like :name', [':name' => "$q%"])
  ->orderBy('valid_payment DESC, name ASC')
```

and don't forget initialize $today

Comment: Thanks. but will the query also include all elements that does not have a valid from and to date? Because most companies wont have it, but I need to prioritise the one that have a valid from and to date.

Comment: updated answer, check this way - add logic field in select with alias and sort by this field first